# How to optimize this complex MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, join

Our website sometimes causes extreme server strain due to a complex MySQL query. The site actually goes down.

The webhoster warned that if we don't get this in order they will suspend our account.

Could someone give some pointers at which parts of this query eat the most resources?

Any suggestions on making this better?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID 
FROM wp_s3mv0r_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_term_relationships ON (wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = wp_s3mv0r_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )  
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt3.post_id )     
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt4 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt4.post_id )  
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt5 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt5.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt6 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt6.post_id )  
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt7 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt7.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt8 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt8.post_id )  
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt9 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt9.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt10 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt10.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt11 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt11.post_id )  
INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta AS mt12 ON ( wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID = mt12.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1  AND (
  wp_s3mv0r_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (11,24,25)
) AND (
  ( wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.meta_key = 'acf_house_minprice' AND CAST(wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '274990' AND '599990' )
  AND
  ( mt1.meta_key = 'acf_house_minlotwidth' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '16' AND '16' )
  AND
  ( mt2.meta_key = 'acf_location_area' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('South of river') )
  AND
  ( mt3.meta_key = 'acf_house_bedroom' AND CAST(mt3.meta_value AS CHAR) = '4' )
  AND
  ( mt4.meta_key = 'acf_house_studyroom' AND CAST(mt4.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  AND
  ( mt5.meta_key = 'acf_house_theaterroom' AND CAST(mt5.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  AND
  ( mt6.meta_key = 'acf_house_alfresco' AND CAST(mt6.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  AND
  ( mt7.meta_key = 'acf_house_activityroom' AND CAST(mt7.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  AND
  ( mt8.meta_key = 'acf_house_doublegarage' AND CAST(mt8.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  AND
  ( mt9.meta_key = 'acf_house_reargarage' AND CAST(mt9.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  AND
  ( mt10.meta_key = 'acf_house_islbeninkitchen' AND CAST(mt10.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  AND
  ( mt11.meta_key = 'acf_house_frontmasterbedroom' AND CAST(mt11.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  AND
  ( mt12.meta_key = 'acf_house_rearmaster' AND CAST(mt12.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
) AND wp_s3mv0r_posts.post_type = 'house' AND (wp_s3mv0r_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
 GROUP BY wp_s3mv0r_posts.ID 
 ORDER BY wp_s3mv0r_posts.post_date DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Why join the same table so many times? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Good question.  I did not write the query.   I just need to optimize it now.

Comment: Then try to find out. We are not here to do your job. Only to help you when your stuck.

Comment: Don't comment if you have absolutely nothing to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT p.ID, count(*) AS 'PostCount'
FROM wp_s3mv0r_posts p INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_term_relationships r ON (p.ID = r.object_id) 
    INNER JOIN wp_s3mv0r_postmeta pm ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
WHERE 
    r.term_taxonomy_id IN (11,24,25) AND p.post_type = 'house' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND (
    (pm.meta_key = 'acf_house_minprice' AND pm.meta_value BETWEEN '274990' AND '599990') OR
    (pm.meta_key = 'acf_house_minlotwidth' AND pm.meta_value BETWEEN '16' AND '16') OR
    (pm.meta_key = 'acf_location_area' AND pm.meta_value = 'South of river') OR
    (pm.meta_key = 'acf_house_bedroom' AND pm.meta_value = '4') OR
    (pm.meta_key IN ('acf_house_studyroom', 'acf_house_theaterroom', 'acf_house_alfresco', 'acf_house_activityroom', 
        'acf_house_doublegarage', 'acf_house_reargarage', 'acf_house_islbeninkitchen', 'acf_house_frontmasterbedroom', 
        'acf_house_rearmaster') AND pm.meta_value > '0'))
GROUP BY p.ID 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: That is a beautiful query.

It's just that those meta_keys should be combined with AND.   I will try if that works now. 

e.g. pm.meta_key = 'acf_house_minlotwidth' AND pm.meta_value BETWEEN '16' AND '16') AND ...

Comment: I change your query to use 'AND' instead of 'OR' in the meta_key part, it cannot find results. Would you know why?

The table 'wp_s3mv0r_postmeta' has a seperate entry for each meta_key.  E.g.  

wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.post_id = 2121, wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.key = acf_house_minprice , wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.value = 200000

next entry

wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.post_id = 2121, wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.key = acf_location_area , wp_s3mv0r_postmeta.value = 'South of river'

Comment: Look at what the original query is doing. The ANDs were used to select the specific rows for each join, not to filter out data. So the updated query uses ORs to pull in those records that match the joins' criteria. That's why replacing ORs with AND will not give you the intended result.